# filling an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an array of objects

```
var photos: Photos[] = [];
```

Photos [] has the following form

```
interface Photos {
  src: string;
  width: number;
  height: number;
}
```

I have a component that accepts an array of strings

```
export type PhotosArray = {
  src: string[]
}

class A extends React.Component<PhotosArray> {

  render() {
    const { src } = this.props;
    return (
    )
};
```

how do i fill my array of objects with an src array?

the component is called as follows

```
<A src={["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]} />
```

I want to ensure that my photos [array] will consist of objects, each object has a src field, width, height, when an array of src enters the component, I want this array to fill the fields of my object, that is, I want it turned out the structure on the similarity of this

```
[
  {
    src: 'first',
    width = some val,
    height = some val
  },
  {
    src: 'second',
    width = some val,
    height = some val
  },
  {
    src: 'third',
    width = some val,
    height = some val
  },
  {
    src: 'fourth',
    width = some val,
    height = some val
  }
]
```

Comment: Explain better what you need. Do you want to create a list of links or a list of images, one per element in the array?

Comment: @mentallurg, I supplemented the question

Answer (score 0):

Modifying state based on props is considered harmful and the lifecycle method that allowed it, `componentWillRecieveProps` is deprecated to be removed soon.

Your alternatives are to pull state up and make `A` fully controlled.

```
class Parent extends Component {

/* function that gets srcs */
getSrc() {
 const src = /* from somewhere */
 const photos = this.state.photos
 for (let i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++)
    photos[i].src = srcs[i]

 this.setState({ photos: [ ...photos ] })
}

render() {
    return (<A photos={this.state.photos} />)
  }
}
```

Comment: No, I need to fill an array of photos: Photos []

Comment: I would not recommend transforming data each time in render() unless it is to map out a collection of values to a collection of JSX Elements. What exactly do you need the object for? Also, btw what you see is indeed an array of photos, it's duck typing.

Comment: @AvanKavish, 
No, once I get an array of strings and I just have to fill my array of objects with my array of strings so that the values ​​from the array fill in the values ​​of the src fields in my array of objects

Comment: ooooh, I see what you mean.

Comment: @AvanKavish, 
I do not understand how to do it

Comment: It's considered bad practice to do that though, they have removed that lifecycle method `componentWillRecieveProps` because it makes code hard to debug. You should consider pulling that state up and making `A` a controlled component.